# Google Maps Api --> One project works without API KEY but another not

Tags: api, maps

i've got two PHP projects in which i use the Google Maps Api to convert adress data into geo coordinates. The first project uses this code (i post ir here in a shorted version) and works:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>
function latlong(adresse) {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    if (geocoder) {
       geocoder.geocode( { 'address': adresse}, function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
             // I NEVER GET IN HERE with my second project
             alert("It works!");
          } else {
            alert('It works not');
          }
       });
     }
}

// Start Converting
latlong('teststreet 10, 91578 Leuterhausen');
```

As you can see, i don't use an API Key in this section

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

but it works anyway (Alert box "It works" is shown).

Now i have built another project with the same code but it does not work (Alert Box "It works not" is shown).

Do you have any idea...

...why the first project works WITHOUT an API key?
...what i have to change in the code so that the second project works?

When i use this code in the header

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[here i place in my key]"
async defer></script>
```

i get the error message: "Google Maps API error: ApiNotActivatedMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#api-not-activated-map-error"

How can i activate the key?

Every help is appreciated.

Best regards

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

If the app has been running before google enforced the use of API keys the app should still run, apps published after the change will require the key ...read here : https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/standard-plan-2016-update

Comment: I have edited my first post. I have tryed itt with an API key but it doesn't work anyway... ;-(

Comment: if you get the error 'Google Maps API error: ApiNotActivatedMapError ' you should follow the instruction in the link you posted = The Google Maps JavaScript API is not activated on your API project. You may need to **enable** the Google Maps JavaScript API under **APIs** in the Google API Console.

Comment: Ah ok...i thought i did activate it because a message said "API is activated". But now i see that i did forget to link/verify my domain. I will do this tommorrow and come back if i fail. Good night

Comment: Any luck with your map? im building one using codeigniter and google maps api.. if you have it on github i wouldnt mind sharing ideas ;)